# MySQL SELECT query containing bit field and string field comparison for NULL returns empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, bit

I have a table that is structured as follows:

```
mysql> desc services;
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uuid                 | binary(16)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| service_number       | varchar(15) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| mobile_imsi          | varchar(15) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| mobile_uid           | varchar(10) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| account_uuid         | binary(16)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| create_date          | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| service_provider_id  | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| service_provider     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| service_carrier_code | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| service_technology   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mobile_msa           | char(2)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mica_acct_seq        | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| payment_type         | char(1)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| price_plan           | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| strategic_flag       | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| app_term_sms_flag    | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modify_date          | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ported_flag          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| prbt_barred_flag     | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
19 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

FIRST QUERY:

```
mysql> select service_number, mobile_imsi, hex(ported_flag) from services where hex(ported_flag) is not null and mobile_imsi is null;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

SECOND QUERY:

```
mysql> select service_number, mobile_imsi, hex(ported_flag) from services where hex(ported_flag) is not null and ifnull(mobile_imsi,0) = '0';
+----------------+-------------+------------------+
| service_number | mobile_imsi | hex(ported_flag) |
+----------------+-------------+------------------+
| 0411720032     | NULL        | 1                |
| 0419269667     | NULL        | 1                |
| 0400000040     | NULL        | 1                |
+----------------+-------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (1.58 sec)
```

What is it about the first query that causes MySQL to return no results? My hunch is that the BIT field in the query is somehow part of the reason, but I don't understand why the IFNULL function here allows it to return the correct result set, whereas a plain old "IS NULL" operation seems to fail.

Answer (score 0):

BIT type in mysql is too bugged. Is better to use Tinyint(1). For all thing with boolean is better tinyint(1) (or enum('Y', 'N').

Try it and tell us